# how to send session's content to a remember me cookie?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, remember-me

I am working  on remember me cookie in `cakephp` which keeps you logged in for 2 weeks.

It is working fine, but what I am passing to be written onto the cookie:

```
$this->request->data['User']['username']
```

Whenever a new user is registered, a hashed ID is created by default.

The remember me cookie just generates a key which checks if its the same user and logins in the backgroud. When the cookie created by cakephp expires (default being four hours), all the information such as user ID, address, etc is lost.

How do I send the ID to be checked instead?

How to I store all of those(user info) even after four hours? (say for around 2 weeks)

Comment: I'm not checking the restricted content. I'm displaying some arbitrary content for particular users by checking their USER ID. so is there any way to send the entire row respect to a particular user(Example: user ID, username, age, created and modified time, etc) to store in a cookie at once? instead of storing each one at a time( the ID being automatically generated)

Comment: Alright..I get it..what about storing session data in a cookie? I mean retrieve data from the session and write it to the cookie..?

Comment: Oh! yes, data from user was required for accessing features in a website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your login function like this

```
 function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        if (!empty($this->data['User']['remember_me'])) {
            $cookie = array();
            $cookie['username'] = $this->data['User']['username'];
            $cookie['password'] = $this->data['User']['password'];
            $this->Cookie->write('Auth.User', $cookie, true, '+2 weeks');
            unset($this->data['User']['remember_me']);
        }
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('Auth.User');
        if (!is_null($cookie)) {
            if ($this->Auth->login($cookie)) {
                //  Clear auth message, just in case we use it.
                $this->Session->delete('Message.auth');
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I am using $this->Session->check('Auth.User.id') to display some restricted content. But how to store the user ID in the cookie because its stored in the database in hashed form?(for displaying the restricted content even after the default 4 hours)

Comment: Use $this->Cookie->write() function to write. $this->Auth->user('id') will return the user ID. The data attribute of cake_sessions table stores all information.

Comment: Thank you. it works but only using the UsersController. In order to login(within 2 weeks) from other controllers as well, i tried using this in Appcontroller under before filter- if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn() && $this->Cookie->read('Auth.User')) 
  $this->redirect('page2');  but it goes to an infinite loop. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: can you please share app controller and user controller code on shidhu047@gmail.com

Comment: My beforefilter() function in Appcontroller now is empty due to the above mentioned error and the login function in userscontroller matches what you have mentioned above

Comment: Put this code in appcontroller beforefilter function if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn() && $this->Cookie->read('Auth.User')) {
 $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('Auth.User');

 $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array(
   'User.username' => $cookie['username'],
   'User.password' => $cookie['password']
  )
 ));

 if ($user && !$this->Auth->login($user['User'])) {
  $this->redirect('/users/logout'); // destroy session & cookie
 }
}